# how to check time when data was saved to file ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

if i use the following to save and retrive data in ios app, how can i get time when file was saved?

```
-(void)saveJsonWithData:(NSData *)data{

     NSString *jsonPath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSUserDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/data.json"];

     [data writeToFile:jsonPath atomically:YES];

}

-(NSData *)getSavedJsonData{
    NSString *jsonPath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSUserDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/data.json"];

    return [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with `NSFileManager` ?

```
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:@"data.json" error:nil];

NSDate *date = [attributes fileModificationDate];
```